# How to implement one interface with multiple variables?

Tags: android, kotlin, interface

I've this flow in my app:

**MainFragment -**

```
private var selectedStartDate: String? = null
private var selectedEndDate: String? = null


    date_picker_start_button.setOnClickListener {
        openDatePickerDialog()
    }

    date_picker_end_button.setOnClickListener {
        openDatePickerDialog()
    }
```

Then `openDatePickerDialog` open Dialog fragment:

```
  override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
     .....
     .....
}
```

And back to my `mainFragment` I implement `OnDateSetListener` interface

```
override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
    Log.i("DatePickerFragmentYear", year.toString())
    Log.i("DatePickerFragmentMonth", month.toString())
    Log.i("DatePickerFragmentDay", dayOfMonth.toString())

 .....
 .....
    selectedStartDate = formattedDate.toString()


}
```

I implemented this for `selectedStartDate` and it works perfect, but How I can implement thie **exact** flow for `selectedEndDate` too?

I can't create multiple `OnDateSetListener` interfaces

Comment: No need to create multiple interface.Create multiple method inside one interface and call the methods according to your requirement.

Comment: How are you attaching the `mainFragment` as an `OnDateSetListener` to your Dialog in the DialogFragment?

Comment: I simply returning the ```DatePickerDialog``` with mainFragment as parent